# javascript reflection to find prototype methods, global scope methods and objects

Tags: javascript, reflection, function-prototypes, prototype-programming

How can I find the prototype methods (not PrototypeJS) that have been defined using reflection? Also, how to find all defined objects and methods in the global scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `for...in` travels all the way down the prototype chain, it doesn't garauntee any specific order, but it should loop through all the properties you're looking for...

```
for ( var property in obj ) {
    //obj[property];
}
```

If you are looking for **only** inherited (via prototype) members, add a `hasOwnProperty()` check...

```
for ( var property in obj ) {
    if ( ! obj.hasOwnProperty(property) ) {
        //obj[property] is an inherited property...
    }
}
```

also, I've never tried this but, but using `window`, I believe you'd find what you are looking for...

```
for ( var property in window) {
    //window[property];
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want `for (property in object) { if (!object.hasOwnProperty(property)) { // property is in object's prototype but not in object } }` to iterate through the prototype properties.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over all prototype properties (including inherited ones):

```
var prototypeData = Object.getPrototypeOf(soomething);
for(var key in prototypeData) {
    // prototypeData[key] is a prototype value
}
```

To see all defined objects, iterate over `window` the same way:

```
for(var key in window) {
    // window[key] is a globally defined value
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to separate those I created?